# TreeView multilevel custom template with buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, treeview

I'm trying to build a template for a treeView in WPF and c#. My problem is that i want to apply a different template for each items level.
I mean that the first item level will be looking different from the second level items.
I don't know how to do this with templates and binding, as i'm new to the technology.
I'm also trying to add buttons to a certain treeviewItems level so i can fire events or commands...
i know this is much to ask, but i hope some one will give me a clue about this or at least if it is possible or not.
Thanks.

Comment: @ Ziad : This is possible. Every TreeNode is a container and you can add your custom controls there.

Comment: its possible! [Click here!](http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=tree+view+wpf+codeproject)

Comment: Thanks guys. You really helped me. I've got a better understanding now!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all objects are of the same type, I can see two methods for achieving this would be to use either the ItemTemplate, or the ItemTemplateSelector properties.

Personally I prefer the XAML approach which would be to use the ItemTemplate property.

In the Template you would specify triggers to alter the appearance based on the level the item is sitting at. To obtain this level, you could specify a converter similar to this:

```
public class TreeViewItemToLevelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is DependencyObject))
            return 0;

        return findLevel(value as DependencyObject, -1);
    }

    private int findLevel(DependencyObject tvi, int level)
    {
        DependencyObject tv = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(tvi) as DependencyObject;

        if (tv != null)
            return findLevel(tv, level + 1);
        else
            return level;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Comment: My vote here. I would to add that you should establish what do you mean as "level". Is it the visual level, or a logic level? As "logic level" I mean the logic importance of the item displayed, not necessarily matching the visual hierarchy. If so, I would suggest to provide a dedicated property "Level" in your model, instead of calculating a "fatty" shown. However, for a visual-way, the "fatty" snippet is okay.

Answer (score 0):

`HierarchicalDataTemplate` has `ItemTemplate` property as well... you can use it.

see this...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chkoenig/archive/2008/05/24/hierarchical-databinding-in-wpf.aspx